# Corebluetooth-writeValue. Why is a break line after 18 characters?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a project with CoreBluetooth. My iPhone works as a sender and another device as an receiver (its not an iPhone). All works fine. I find the device finds services and characteristics.

But I can only send a string of 18 characters, but I would like to send way longer strings. I tried two different ways to create the data.

```
NSString * test = @"1/1e0c/halloweristfnsadklfklasjdfkas";
const char *s=[test UTF8String];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];
```

and

```
NSString * test = @"1/1e0c/halloweristfnsadklfklasjdfkas";    
NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic: characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Is this because of the time interval? Is it possible to send longer Strings. Is the data I send to big? Is it a problem of NSString?

Comment: You can only send about 20 bytes per transmission with Bluetooth Low Energy

Comment: Yea. My problem is that after the string it automatically adds a line break. Otherwise i would send da String in 2 packages. But maybe its a problem of my end device. thanks @Paulw11